# Flash message fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a flash message with a fade in and out effect using `jQuery`. can someone please suggest the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Sure:

```
$(function() {
   $('#flash').delay(500).fadeIn('normal', function() {
      $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut();
   });
});
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jacobrelkin/EM6xx/2)

Comment: Can't get fadeIN to work, out works fine -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278586/fade-not-working-for-flash-message-in-rails if interested.  Thanks boss!

Answer (score 2):

This is a modification of Jacob's answer above. 
You can't fade in something that isn't hidden initially.

Instructions:

put an id of flash into your flash message, like this (my flash messages are stored here app/views/layouts/_flashmessages.html.erb):

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="well lead" id="flash"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

make a new file called assets/javascripts/flash.js.coffee

put this in (beware of spaces, make sure all indentations are tabs):

```
jQuery ->

    $('#flash').hide().delay(800).fadeIn(800).delay(4000).fadeOut(800)
```