# Fade Not Working for Flash Message in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The following function fades out properly but does not fade in.  I  got it from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801561/flash-message-fade-effect) (thank you Jacob) when looking for a solution.  It works in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jacobrelkin/EM6xx/2/), just not in my app.  I do not have turbolinks enabled (it really toys too hard with my app).  Could that be the reason?

Any ideas?

```
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('.alert').delay(500).fadeIn('normal', function() {
            $(this).delay(1500).fadeOut();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Is `.alert` on your page when it loads?

Comment: Oh I see, what you mean, this may be the problem.  Gah, I thought you were asking me if the selector was proper at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question you meant the '#flash' element has `display:none` initially in its css style; Make sure you got that line in you application.css.