# Using Flask and Python - can't make messages appear and disappear

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I'm new to the world of html/javascript and am building my first site using Python/Flask with a SQLAlchemy backend. I have a basic version the site working but am having some trouble with styles. I can't make messages (Flask flash) appear and disappear. I found a similar question on SO ([Flash message fade effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801561/flash-message-fade-effect)) and the JFiddle works great. I adapted the code to my use and it didn't work: the text stayed hidden when "display:none;" was included in my CSS. When removed, I saw the text but it never disappeared. I figured other CSS styling may be interfering, so I created a new page for testing.

For the life of me, I can't figure out why this works in JFiddle (and clearly for the OP on the other question) but not for me. There are no other scripts or styles to interfere. I think if I could get this test working, I can adapt it for my much more complicated actual code using actual Flask flash messages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

**Test.html**

```
<div id="flash">Blah blah blah</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
       $('#flash').delay(500).fadeIn('normal', function() {
          $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut();
       });
    });
</script>
```

**test.css**

```
#flash {
    display:none;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff
}
```

Comment: do you load `jQuery` in HTML's head ? In Chrome/Firefox you can open DevTool to see console with JavaScript errors and server's responses (tab "Network") to check if it loads `jQuery` and runs your script without errors.

Comment: Missing jQuery was the issue. Thank you! If you put that in an answer I'd be happy to accept it. Included the following line (but will integrate fully into my app in prod):

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Char `$` means you use jQuery which you have to load in HTML`s head.

---

You can [download it](https://jquery.com/download/) and load from your server or use [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) like

[Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries#jquery) :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[CDNjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/) :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```